# Probability of a prime number of points on an elliptic curve over a prime field

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

Suppose we have some elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb F_p$, with $p$ a large prime. Let $n$ be the number of points on the curve. I am interested in what is currently known about the probability* that $n$ is prime (i.e. some reasonable lower bound on this probability).

$n$ is well-known to be within the "Hasse-Weil interval":
$$t := \left| n - (p + 1) \right| \le 2 \sqrt p$$

By PNT there are something like $\frac {4 \sqrt p} {\log p}$ primes in this interval, but obviously the probability distribution of $t$ in this interval is non-uniform, so this does not directly give us a good bound. Is there perhaps some known constant multiple of this that is a correct bound?

*Note: To clarify the meaning of "probability": Suppose that the curve was chosen at random (uniformly) from all the nonsingular elliptic curves of form $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: "but **obviously** the probability distribution of $t$ in this interval is non-uniform". I am not saying you are wrong, but I don't see why it is obvious.

Comment: Ok, maybe the word obvious is a bit too much here, but from what I've read on the subject I understood that it's known and basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [known](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/Broker.pdf), that as in your setting, when $p$ is prime every possible integer in the Hasse-interval $\mathcal{H}_p$ arises as group order of an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_p$. For arbitrary prime powers $q = p^f$
this is not generally true: there are often not enough supersingular curves to cover the cases $N \equiv 1 \mod p$.

Galbraith and McKee [gives](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/cm.pdf) a formula for the probability that a randomly
chosen elliptic curve over a finite field has a prime number of points. The conjecture is the following: Let $P_1$ be the probability that a number within $\mathcal{H}_p$ is prime. Let $C_2\approx0.6601$ be the Hardy-Littlewood twin primes constant. Then the probability that an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ has a prime number of points is asymptotic to $c_pP_1$ as $p\to  \infty$, where

$$c_p=\frac{3}{2}C_2\prod_{l\vert p-1,l>2}\Big(1+\frac{1}{(l+1)(l-2)}\Big) .$$

One might say that $P_1\approx\frac{1}{\log p}$, however this estiamte might not be precise in short intervals.

If all numbers of points in $\mathcal{H}_p$ were equally likely, then we would have $c_p = 1$. The expression given for $c_p$ lies between
about $0.44$ and $0.62$, indicating the phenomenon that prime numbers of
points are disfavoured.

Even though prime numbers of points are seem to be disfavoured by nature, [you can](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~schmidtt/ourPapers/SavasKoc/ches01curve.pdf) [efficiently generate](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/bs.pdf) such curves in poly-time, ie. in $\mathcal{O}(\log^{3} p)$.